# Rcpp code example cppFunction

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am trying run a code of "Seamless R and C++ Integration with Rcpp" (Page 32, Listing 2.10) but It´s giving a error. Could someone explain to me why is not working? Thanks

```
Code <- ' 
#include <gsL/gsl_const_mksa.h>           // decl of constants 
std::vector<double> volumes() { 
std::vector<double> v(5); 
v[0] = GSL_CONST_MKSA_US_GALLON;       // 1 US gallon 
v[1] = GSL_CONST_MKSA_CANADIAN_GALLON; // 1 Canadian gallon 
v[2] = GSL_CONST_MKSA_UK_GALLON;       // 1 UK gallon 
v[3] = GSL_CONST_MKSA_QUART;           // 1 quart 
v[4] = GSL_CONST_MKSA_PINT;            // 1 pint 
return v; 
}' 

gslVolumes <- cppFunction(code, depends="RcppGSL")
```

This is the message error:

```
file16e2b6cb966.cpp: In function ‘SEXPREC* sourceCpp_52966_volumes()’: 
file16e2b6cb966.cpp:30: error: ‘__result’ was not declared in this scope 
make: *** [file16e2b6cb966.o] Error 1 
llvm-g++-4.2 -arch x86_64 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/include -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include -I/usr/local/include  -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/RcppGSL/include"    -fPIC  -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c file16e2b6cb966.cpp -o file16e2b6cb966.o 
Erro em sourceCpp(code = code, env = env, rebuild = rebuild, showOutput = showOutput,  : 
  Error 1 occurred building shared library.
```

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you have typos:

```
Code <- ' 
#include <gsL/gsl_const_mksa.h>           // decl of constants
```

That should be `code <-` with lower-case `c`, and then `#include <gsl/gsl_const_mksa.h>`   with a lower-case 'ell'.

In general, I recomment to switch on verbose mode:

```
gslVolumes <- cppFunction(code, depends="RcppGSL", verbose=TRUE)
```

which would have told you about

1. `object code not found` from the first error, and
2. `file....cpp:10:63: fatal error: gsL/gsl_const_mksa.h: No such file or directory`

about the missing header.

But I do see now that with the current versions, I also get `__result not declared`. Will
investigate.

*Edit:* It's a bug / change. It worked when I wrote the chapter, now you need to

1. remove the line with the `#include <gsl/gsl_const_mksa.h>` from the `code` assignment
2. add a new `includes=...` argument to the `cppFunction()` call as below:

Corrected call:

```
 gslVolumes <- cppFunction(code, depends="RcppGSL",
                           includes="#include <gsl/gsl_const_mksa.h>")
```

Comment: Is there an errata/updates page for the book? I looked a few other places before finding this SO page.

Comment: Nope, I am a little behind creating one.  But if you email me entries changes get better I get started.  Not for the next few weeks unfortunately.  As for "help" on Rcpp, the documentation has and will point to the rcpp-devel list.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what Dirk said, I recommend that you promote the code to a .cpp file.

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppGSL)]]
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_const_mksa.h>           // decl of constants 

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::vector<double> volumes() { 
  std::vector<double> v(5); 
  v[0] = GSL_CONST_MKSA_US_GALLON;       // 1 US gallon 
  v[1] = GSL_CONST_MKSA_CANADIAN_GALLON; // 1 Canadian gallon 
  v[2] = GSL_CONST_MKSA_UK_GALLON;       // 1 UK gallon 
  v[3] = GSL_CONST_MKSA_QUART;           // 1 quart 
  v[4] = GSL_CONST_MKSA_PINT;            // 1 pint 
  return v; 
}
```

Then, you can `sourceCpp` that file.

Comment: Very helpful; I tried something _similar_ unsuccessfully, but this works. Note that the function resulting from `sourceCpp`ing this file is called by issuing `volumes()` in `R` (rather than `gslVolumes()` in the original example).